# git rebase after merging published branch?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I want to use rebase to remove meaningless merge-commits.
At the same time, I want to preserve the branch history when I branched off to develop some feature.

Basically,

- `git rebase` when pull from remote develop branch into my local develop branch.
  (by using `git config branch.develop.rebase true`)
- `git merge` when merging in feature branch into the local develop branch.

I've read 'do not rebase published commits' and am afraid if my use case violates it.

Suppose the following scenario.

origin/develop:

```
A - B - C
```

develop:

```
A - B 
     \ 
      D - E - F
```

featureA (published):

```
A - B
     \
      D
       \
        G - H
```

Now, I merge featureA onto develop.

```
A - B
     \
      D - E - F - I
       \        /
        G - H -
```

Then, rebase develop (I guess D here is actually D', not sure about E ~ I are E' ~ I')

```
A - B - C
         \
          D - E - F - I
           \        /
            G - H -
```

Now the puzzling part, what happens to someone who has worked on the published featureA?

```
A - B
     \
      D
       \
        G - H 
             \
              J
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the person who fetches from remote after you have pushed will see something like this:

```
A - B - C
     \    \
      D    D' - E' - F' - I'(remote/develop, remote/feature)
       \    \             |
        \    G' - H' - - -
         \   
          G - H 
               \
                J(Feature)
```

Might not be exact, but point is, it will complicate the history! Over all, to increase more confusion you have merge+rebase that too after publishing!

Never do that!

Comment: I guess this should be an another question, but if you ever publish your feature branch, is there a way to use `rebase` pull? with `git config branch.develop.rebase true`?